# Scala reading and splitting long process output

Tags: scala, concurrency, process, pipe

What is the "best" way to read in a long comma-delimited file and convert it into a sequence of arrays in scala?

I had thought something like this:

```
import scala.sys.process._
val cmdList = List("perl","-e","""print join(",",map { rand } (1..5))."\n" foreach (1..500000)""");
val data = {
  val listBuffer = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Array[String]]()
  cmdList.lineStream_!.foreach { (line) => listBuffer += line.split(",") }
  listBuffer.toList
}
```

would be appropriate, but on my box from the scala REPL, I get,

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
  at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:2694)
```

I'd like to process lines one-by-one as they are produced.  I am using scala 2.11.7. Even better would be to wrap up the result in a Future, as my data isn't immediately needed.

Comment: I suspect this is key:  [Change to Java substring behavior makes this type of parsing memory intensive](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/1qw73v/til_oracle_changed_the_internal_string/)  Need to keep whole rows around and possibly create an implicit conversion to the split representation on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate each line char by char and keeping track of how many chars you have read split them into smaller arrays.